# Initiating Private Property via loop and checking exists before accessing it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jobs

I'm using Laravel Job to process some data, passing a device object which has json array in it.

defined private properties, Note there are way more than just 3

```
private int $width;
private int $depth;
private int $height;
```

Then initiating it via loop

```
foreach($this->device->data as $key => $val)
{
        $this->{$key} = $val;
}
```

Now before using it I want to check if they initiated properly before running my methods.

Currently checking before running each method like

```
if(ISSET($this->waste) && ISSET($this->height))
            $this->level = $this->getLevelFromDistance($this->waste, $this->height);
```

Is it the only way to go about this? or is there a better way to do this?

My ultimate object is to check if properties exists then process the object otherwise log an alert for user.

Comment: How object is created? Maybe good solution is to not allow create invalid object and alert user in this point.

Comment: I thought so too, but it's a device Laravel model object and devices has different types and variants and some variant might not have dimensions.

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but I think you could have own data model. Each device type should be separated class.